# (ReactJS) CSS changes after inserting a component into another component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Why does my css get messed up when I stick `<YTdisplay />` inside of a bootstrap `Jumbotron`. I would think the Jumbotron should fit whatever is inserted inside of it. But instead its just floating over the Jumbotron. Any suggestions?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import YTdisplay from './youtube_display';

const Media = () => {
  return (
    <Jumbotron>
      <YTdisplay />
    </Jumbotron>
  );
};

export default Media;
```

CSS

```
/* ******************************
 media area css
****************************** */

.search-bar {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-bar input {
  width: 75%;
}

.video-item img {
  max-width: 64px;
}

.video-detail .details {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.list-group-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Please post your CSS. Probably, the CSS is not specific enough, causing it to override properties that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Sorry just posted the css

Comment: This is most likely going to be a CSS specificity issue, and has little to do with React itself. You should inspect the resulting CSS to determine the problematic CSS that is preventing the behavior you want. But you have not provided us with enough information to help you. For starters, we don't know the result (output) of your nested components and we don't know for certain your expected outcome. What I can tell you, is that the CSS you posted is not easily extendable (or "plays well with others"), because its too generic, which means it could easily mess with CSS from other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that the div doesn't scale to the contents. Try setting `display: block;` to the parent div.

Also, declarations like this: `.video-item img {` tell the browser: "in the `.video-item` div, do the following to ALL images inside the div", which may be too broad. Try changing those lines to something like `.video-item > img`, which means: only the DIRECT child.

If you'd like to see a complete working example, please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and post it here.